# Yahoo API: is geo API closed? (formerly where.yahooapis.com)

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-api

does anybody know if the standard yahoo geo/where-api is has been closed?
The api was accessible (untili yesterday) on where.yahooapis.com?

Regards

Answer (score 4):

OK, the public Yahoo Statement is here:

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/ysearchboss/message/5163

Comment: Url seems obsolete now, you should delete that answer to avoid downvoting friend

Answer (score 2):

A quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=where.yahooapis.com) points me to:

- [Yahoo! BOSS Geo Services](http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/)

This Yahoo [forum post](http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/PlaceFinder-Product-Announcements/http-where-yahooapis-com-geocode-appid-flags-P-not-returning-serialized-PHP-but/1349181261898-870cf85e-dc2f-4291-92c5-41754397504d) also offers details about the `where` API.

Comment: Yes, i've seen the BOSS server site, but it seems its no more free. The forum you have posted includes only old threads, from last year or earlier. An announcement telling that i will be no more free cant be found :-( (and yet, since its an important announcement, i would have expected a thread to be there?)